# PieDonut not showing donut labels

Tags: r, pie-chart, donut-chart

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I'm trying to make a simple PieDonut chart using `webr` (https://cardiomoon.github.io/webr/reference/PieDonut.html) as

`PieDonut(dados, aes(status, group), ratioByGroup = FALSE, r0 = 0)`

However, it does not return donut labels (C, NC, P, SP, ST), only the value represented by the sum of C+NC+P+SP+ST (110 for Ingresso and 56 for Egresso)

[image]

Warning messages:
1: In max(nchar(levels(df3$label))) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: `guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> = "none")` instead.
3: `guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> = "none")` instead.

Any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I worked around a bit and got to an answer:

```
#Adding a frequency count to each observation
dados$freq = 1

PD = dados %>% group_by(status, Categoria) %>% summarise(n = sum(freq))
print(PD)
```

[image]

```
#Then...
PieDonut(PD, aes(status, Categoria, count = n),
         r0 = 0,
         showRatioThreshold = 0.001,
         showPieName = F,
         title = "Some title here",
         ratioByGroup = F)
```

Thing is: I did some piedonuts before using the same package and I had no issues avoiding the `count` argument. Don't know what happened about that.

[image]